# Are morphisms between projective curves finite?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, schemes, algebraic-curves

For convenient we discuss about projective curves. Hartshorne II 6.8 proved a non-trivial morphism from a nonsingular curve to another curve is finite. So I'm wondering if we can prove the consequence for any curves and non-trivial morphism.
I tried to do this by following:
For any point y on Y, I take an affine neighborhood $V=\operatorname{Spec} A$ of it, and set $U=f^{-1}(V)$. The fiber is $\operatorname{Spec}(\mathcal{O}(U)\otimes_A k(y))$. $\mathcal{O}(U)\otimes_A k(y)$ is a finite length k(y)-module hence Artinian, so the fiber is finite and discrete, therefore $f$ is quasi-finite.

I know there is a consequence quasi-finite+proper=finite, but I have no ideal how to prove it(does anyone have a ref?) and I want to deal with the problem (in projective case) using a rather elementary method, but I cant think up one.

Comment: It’s actually a non-obvious result in general. You can check https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/02LQ for a general proof. To show projective+quasi-finite implies finite for locally Noetherian schemes, you can read Chapters 4.4 (and 5.3 for a technical theorem important on its own and used in the proof – the finiteness of cohomology modules for a projective scheme) of *Algebraic geometry and arithmetic curves* by Qing Liu.

Comment: For a (mostly) elementary proof which is an exercise in that same book, you can proceed as follows: let $X \subset \mathbb{P}^n_Y$ be a closed subset and let $y \in Y$ be such that $X_y$ is finite. Then you can find a principal closed subset $V_+(P)$ not meeting $X_y$. Then the image of $V_+(P)$ in $Y$ is closed and contains not $y$ so there is $y\in V \subset Y$ affine which doesn’t meet said image. Then $X_V=X \cap D_+(P)$ is affine too (closed in $D_+(P)$ affine), so $X_V \rightarrow V$ is affine projective hence finite.

Comment: @Mindlack Thanks for your hints on the problem, I'm exactly working on the ZMT(the version that claimed fibers are connected), and try to handle the case of projective curves without the formal function theorem.

Comment: I also find a proof for "finite=proper+affine=proper+quasi-finite" on Vakil's notes(version2015) 10.3.8 and 29.6.2, but the proof there also uses the ZMT.